# Is this relationship between vector products $a⋅(b×c) = (a×b)⋅c$ valid

Tags: linear-algebra

If we have this vector product of three vectors $a$ $b$ and $c$:
$$ a⋅(b×c) $$

Is it true to assume that

$$ a⋅(b×c) = (a×b)⋅c = (a×c)⋅b $$

And if so is there a name for this rule?

Comment: $a\cdot(b\times c)=-b\cdot(a\times c)$; the scalar triple product is unchanged under a circular shift of its three operands:   $ a ⋅ ( b × c ) = b ⋅ ( c × a ) = c ⋅ ( a × b )$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I understand, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$[A,B,C]=A.(B\times C)$, then the cyclic products:
$$[A,B,C]=[B,C,A]=[C,A,B]$$
As $$(A\times B).C=C.(A \times B)=[C,A,B]=[A,B,C]$$ $$=A.(B \times C)$$

Answer (score 2):

It is not true to assume this, as the vector product is not commutative (i.e. $\vec a\times\vec b= -(\vec b\times \vec a)$).

However, for applications of the triple scalar product (e.g. determining volume of parallelepiped, determining whether three points are coplanar, etc), notice that you are taking the absolute value of the triple scalar product, in which case the order does not matter.